# Do all ADSL modems support fastpath?

Tags: adsl, adsl2+

I'm thinking about asking my ISP to switch me from an interleaved to a fastpath ADSL2+ setup. However, do I need a modem that supports this, or is fastpath supported by all ADSL2+ modems?

My "gateway" device (router/switch/modem combo) is a very old and very basic [BaudTec T263R1 (Conn X)](http://www.baudtec.com.tw/p_t263r1.htm).

Comment: Are you sure your modem is even using interleaving? With ADSL2+, it's only activated on-demand.

Comment: @DanielB AFAIK, interleaving is the default so that users don't complain about connection drop-outs. But unfortunately, my modem doesn't tell me if the connection is interleaved (the modem is something like 9 years old.) It's not mentioned anywhere, which is why I don't know if fastpath is even supported by all modems.